# break enclosing switch statement from inner for loop?

Tags: c#, .net, controls, structure, goto

Consider the following C#:

```
// C# .net
switch(x)
   {
    case 1:
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int val = getValue(i);
            if (val == 0)
                goto endswitch;
        }
        doMoreStuff();
        break;
    case 2:
        doSomeThingElse();
        break;
    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
endswitch: ;
```

I've written code similar to the above code sample.  The problem is that I need to break the switch statement from inside the inner for loop.  If I put a `break` statement there, it will only break the inner for loop and then proceed to `doMoreStuff()`, which is not what I need.

The alternative that seems to work best here is a `goto` statement, but I know this is frowned upon.

Another alternative is to keep track of a separate variable inside the for loop, but this adds lines of code and is less elegent.

What is the best way to do this?

**Update:** I have read that there is a way to do this in JavaScript.  It works like this: (http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/break.html)

```
// JavaScript
outer_loop:
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
   document.write("<BR>" + "outer " + i + ":   ");
   for(j=0; j<5; j++)
   {
      document.write("inner " + j + " ");
      if(j==x)
         break outer_loop;
   }
}
```

Is something like this possible in C#?

Comment: Is `val` a `bool` or an `int`? Your code won't compile as it is.

Comment: Code won't compile because of missing paranthesis "{". It must be a typo from user.

Comment: Also from code its clear that val x is an integer.

Comment: Consider replacing a `switch` statement with polymorphism if appropriate. See the "[Tell, Don't Ask]" principle (http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can abstract the check to a method with a return flag:

```
switch(x)
{
    case 1:
        if (ShouldDoMoreStuff())
            doMoreStuff();
        break;
    case 2:
        doSomeThingElse();
        break;
    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}


private bool ShouldDoMoreStuff()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var val = getValue(i);
        if (val == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Just to expand, you *can* use the goto as you had, but it's generally frowned upon, especially in such a trivial case.  *Sometimes* it's useful when you have many, many nested loops or switches but that's usually a sign that maybe you should refactor/redesign a bit.  As you pointed out, you can store a local variable and do a check but that's a bit obtuse/smelly as you realized.  I prefer this method I posted above as it becomes pretty readable to work with.

EDIT: Regarding your comment and edited question, I do not believe a analogous language feature to your JavaScript code exists in C#.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w%28VS.80%29.aspx (emphasis added):

> Within nested statements, the break statement terminates only the do,
>   for, switch, or while statement that **immediately encloses it**. You can
>   use a return or goto statement to transfer control from within more
>   deeply nested structures.

Comment: This is one way of avoiding `goto`.  Is there not some way to specify exactly which control structure a `break` statement is supposed to break?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: I do not believe so, maybe in some languages but not C#.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w%28VS.80%29.aspx : _"Within nested statements, the break statement terminates only the do, for, switch, or while statement that immediately encloses it. You can use a return or goto statement to transfer control from within more deeply nested structures."_  So even the MSDN suggests using `return` or `goto` to exit nested structures.

Comment: and with that comment, you just answered my original question.  Thank you.

Comment: Oops, didn't even see this before I posted my answer... +1 for broader explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of problem caused by too much thinking. You could simply have a boolean that will be altered if your condition is met before the for loop and run your method only if the boolean is true, e.g.:

```
switch(x)
   {
    case 1:
        bool donrun;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int val = getValue(i);
            if (val == 0)
                donrun = true;
        }
        if(!donrun) doMoreStuff();
        break;
    case 2:
        doSomeThingElse();
        break;
    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: Actually, Daniel considered that option but didn't post a code sample: _"Another alternative is to keep track of a separate variable inside the for loop, but this adds lines of code and is less elegent."_  But I've been caught doing this in more than one spot >.> I try not to though.

Comment: Hmm, I don't even see anything wrong with his approaches in the first place... aesthetically though, I also agree your approach is better than this approach.

Comment: For the most part I agree.  This is a pretty trivial case, and especially if this is just a small private implementation detail then it's not a big deal.  In my experience, I try to avoid as much work/clutter as possible in switch/case blocks because it's very easy to lose yourself in what's going on and tracking logical flow.  Throw `goto` in a switch doesn't help things. Not to mention having a `goto` pointing to a `case` within the switch --which is valid-- just puts the cherry on top!

Comment: @Chris, sounds like you might make a good contestant at the obfuscated C contest!

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: too much work.  It's like purposely trying to write in Internet shorthand. Thanks for the compliment!

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yh, I learnt that the hard way, I usually avoid anything more than 10 -15 lines in any method I write. And Daniel, the contest looks more like application of [Stemmer's Algorithm...](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/)